# Dynamic routing to IO sink in Apache Beam

Tags: apache-beam, clickhouse

Looking at the example for `ClickHouseIO` for `Apache Beam` the name of the output table is hard coded:

```
 pipeline
   .apply(...)
   .apply(
     ClickHouseIO.<POJO>write("jdbc:clickhouse:localhost:8123/default", "my_table"));
```

Is there a way to dynamically route a record to a table based on its content?

I.e. if the record contains `table=1`, it is routed to `my_table_1`, `table=2` to `my_table_2` etc.

Comment: would be able to help me in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58075897/need-to-insert-rows-in-clickhouseio-from-apache-beamdataflow

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the ClickHouseIO is still [in development](https://jira.apache.org/jira/browse/BEAM-5964) does not support this. The BigQueryIO does support [Dynamic Destinations](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/io/built-in/google-bigquery/#using-dynamic-destinations), so it is possible with Beam.

The limitation in the current ClickHouseIO is around transforming data to match the destination table schema. As a workaround, if your destination tables are known at pipeline creation time you could create a ClickHouseIO per table, then use the data to route to the correct instance of the IO.

You might want to file a feature request in the [Beam bug tracker](https://jira.apache.org/jira/) for this.