# Array type in clickhouseIO for apache beam(dataflow)

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, dataflow, clickhouse

I am using Apache Beam to consume json and insert into clickhouse.

I am currently having a problem with the Array data type.

Everything works fine before I add an array type of field

```java
Schema.Field.of("inputs.value", Schema.FieldType.array(Schema.FieldType.INT64).withNullable(true))
```

Code for the transformations

```java
p.apply(transformNameSuffix + "ReadFromPubSub",
        PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription(chainConfig.getPubSubSubscriptionPrefix() + "transactions").withIdAttribute(PUBSUB_ID_ATTRIBUTE))
        .apply(transformNameSuffix + "ReadFromPubSub", ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, Row>() {
            @ProcessElement
            public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
                String item = c.element();

                //System.out.print(item);
                Transaction transaction = JsonUtils.parseJson(item, Transaction.class);
                c.output(Row.withSchema(Schemas.TRANSACTIONS)
                        .addValues(*****,
                                   *****
                                   .......

                transaction.getInputValues()).build());}

        })).setRowSchema(Schemas.TRANSACTIONS).apply(
        ClickHouseIO.<Row>write(
                chainConfig.getClickhouseJDBCURI(),
                chainConfig.getTransactionsTable())
                .withMaxRetries(3)
                .withMaxInsertBlockSize(1)
                .withInitialBackoff(Duration.standardSeconds(5))
                .withInsertDeduplicate(true)
                .withInsertDistributedSync(false));
```

The method that generates the inputs

```java
public List<Long> getInputValues() {
    List<Long> values = Lists.newArrayList();

    for (TransactionInput eachInput : inputs) {
        System.out.print(eachInput.getValue());
        values.add(eachInput.getValue());
    }

    return values;
}
```

The error I am getting is :

```sh
ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 33, host: 35.202.46.77, port: 8123; Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data. Bytes read: 6. Bytes expected: 15. (version 19.17.4.11 (official build))

    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:58)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:28)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:875)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:851)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:106)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:141)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:764)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:758)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.flush(ClickHouseIO.java:427)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.processElement(ClickHouseIO.java:411)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.AutoValue_ClickHouseIO_WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:222)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.processElementInReadyWindows(SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator.processElement(ParDoEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.processElement(DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.java:54)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data. Bytes read: 6. Bytes expected: 15. (version 19.17.4.11 (official build))

    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:53)
    ... 22 more

Feb 06, 2020 9:04:38 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn flush
WARNING: Error writing to ClickHouse. Retry attempt[1]
ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 33, host: 35.202.46.77, port: 8123; Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data. Bytes read: 6. Bytes expected: 93. (version 19.17.4.11 (official build))

    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:58)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:28)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.checkForErrorAndThrow(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:875)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:851)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:106)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.Writer.send(Writer.java:141)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:764)
    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseStatementImpl.sendRowBinaryStream(ClickHouseStatementImpl.java:758)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.flush(ClickHouseIO.java:427)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn.processElement(ClickHouseIO.java:411)
    at org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.AutoValue_ClickHouseIO_WriteFn$DoFnInvoker.invokeProcessElement(Unknown Source)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.invokeProcessElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:222)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimpleDoFnRunner.processElement(SimpleDoFnRunner.java:183)
    at org.apache.beam.repackaged.direct_java.runners.core.SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.processElementInReadyWindows(SimplePushbackSideInputDoFnRunner.java:78)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.ParDoEvaluator.processElement(ParDoEvaluator.java:216)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.processElement(DoFnLifecycleManagerRemovingTransformEvaluator.java:54)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.processElements(DirectTransformExecutor.java:160)
    at org.apache.beam.runners.direct.DirectTransformExecutor.run(DirectTransformExecutor.java:124)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.Throwable: Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data. Bytes read: 6. Bytes expected: 93. (version 19.17.4.11 (official build))

    at ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.specify(ClickHouseExceptionSpecifier.java:53)
    ... 22 more

Feb 06, 2020 9:04:39 PM org.apache.beam.sdk.io.clickhouse.ClickHouseIO$WriteFn flush
WARNING: Error writing to ClickHouse. Retry attempt[1]
ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 33, host: 35.202.46.77, port: 8123; Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data. Bytes read: 5. Bytes expected: 2641. (version 19.17.4.11 (official build)
```

Clikhouse schema:

```sql
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions_streaming_small ( 
  *****, 
  *****, 
  inputs Nested ( value Nullable(UInt64) ) ) 
ENGINE = MergeTree() PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(block_date_time)
```

What is the problem?

[ClickHouse version 19.17.4.11 (official build)]

Comment: try to remove *.withNullable(true)*, it looks like you operate with non-nullable Long-type. Could you provide the schema of target table in CH and version of CH?

Comment: 19.17.4.11
```
```

Comment: CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS transactions_streaming_small (
    *****,
    *****,
    inputs Nested (
        value Nullable(UInt64)
    )
)
ENGINE = MergeTree()
PARTITION BY toYYYYMM(block_date_time)

Comment: could you test this definition *Schema.Field.of("inputs.value", Schema.FieldType.array(Schema.FieldType.INT64, true))*?

Comment: did not work.
I am getting the error

ru.yandex.clickhouse.except.ClickHouseException: ClickHouse exception, code: 33, host: 35.202.46.77, port: 8123; Code: 33, e.displayText() = DB::Exception: Cannot read all data. Bytes read: 6. Bytes expected: 117. (version 19.17.4.11 (official build))

Comment: type of array item in DB is *Nullable(UInt64)* when on Beam-side is *Nullable(INT64)* - could you use unsigned on both sides?

Comment: could you try to localize the issue? Let's create the test table *test_table* with the same schema as *transactions_streaming_small* and additional columns - *array_uint64 Array(UInt64), array_uint64n Array(Nullable(UInt64)), array_int64 Array(Int64), array_int64n Array(Nullable(Int64))*. Insert several test rows into this table and try to load data from each extra column one by one to find the failed one.

Comment: Thanks. 
So, UINT64 and INT64 without nullable works.

            Schema.Field.of("inputs.value", Schema.FieldType.array(Schema.FieldType.INT64, false)),
            Schema.Field.of("inputs.value_int", Schema.FieldType.array(Schema.FieldType.INT64, false))


    inputs Nested (
        value UInt64,
        value_int Int64
    )

The nullable ones are throwing a problem

Comment: I need nullable fields how do I overcome this problem?

Comment: I would try to localize the problem to overcome it. There are three components in the data pipeline: [CH Beam SDK](https://github.com/apache/beam/tree/master/sdks/java/io/clickhouse), JDBC and ClickHouse. Let's insert data to CH using [clickhouse-client](https://clickhouse.tech/docs/en/interfaces/cli/) and then using JDBC to exclude/or detect the source of the problem.